# How exactly does the Windows telnet client work?

Tags: windows, telnet

I'm slightly confused here. Usually when I connect Windows telnet to a simple echo server, it echoes every keystroke.

Now, for some reason it stacks a few of them and sends them to the server. Is this normal behavior? Is there any reason for this strange inconsistency?

Example:

Client:

```
>>blahblahblah

>>
```

Echo server:

```
I recieved "b"
I recieved "lahbl"
I recieved "ahbla"
I recieved "h\r\n"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the buffering on both sides.  The client waits for the end of line to send the available characters.  The echo server reads, but read gets what's available, and depending on the randomness of the network and buffering, this may be anything from 1 character up to all you sent.

With TCP, everything is guaranteed to get there, but not necessarily at the same time or in the same chunks that you sent it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this was what I was looking for. Do most Windows telnet-like clients do the same thing?

Comment: there are typically some options to control if every character is sent separately, and if the echo is done locally or not.   Also, telnet is pretty much superceded by ssh which encrypts it's traffic.

Comment: The Telnet client doesn't wait for the end of the line to send characters, unless line mode has been enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite positive, this depends on your typing speed.

If I were to write such an interactive client, I'd queue up keystrokes up to a time interval that is still instant to the human, but actually long for a computer. I'd start a send operation if my buffer gets full (really high speed typing - most possibly redirected input) or after the above timeout occurs.

By doing so, I can reduce felt latency by sending a bigger payload with each packet, thus reducing the felt latency to by 1/n with n being the average number of keystrokes in a packet. As a positive side effect, this would make (slightly) better use of network resources.

To verify my hypothesis, use the clipboard to paste a longer piece of text into the telnet client.

Comment: I wonder why the client does that... I always found it odd to immediately send keystrokes.

Comment: The Windows telnet client (as most telnet clients out there) come from a time, where network latency was in the 100s of milliseconds (think: Phone modem). Waiting for a complete line was not an option, as local echo and remote echo could work quite different. So this is a best-effort way to deliver single keystrokes (echo!) and still keep packets from carrying a single-byte payload (latency!)